# How to send `files_upload_session_append_v2` in parallel? (Dropbox API, Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to upload a large file to Dropbox via Dropbox API in a parallel way (so it will be uploaded faster than in a sequential way).

The documentation says

```
By default, upload sessions require you to send content of the file in
sequential order via consecutive :meth:`files_upload_session_start`,
:meth:`files_upload_session_append_v2`,
:meth:`files_upload_session_finish` calls. For better performance, you
can instead optionally use a ``UploadSessionType.concurrent`` upload
session. To start a new concurrent session, set
``UploadSessionStartArg.session_type`` to
``UploadSessionType.concurrent``. After that, you can send file data in
concurrent :meth:`files_upload_session_append_v2` requests. Finally
finish the session with :meth:`files_upload_session_finish`. There are
couple of constraints with concurrent sessions to make them work. You
can not send data with :meth:`files_upload_session_start` or
:meth:`files_upload_session_finish` call, only with
:meth:`files_upload_session_append_v2` call. Also data uploaded in
:meth:`files_upload_session_append_v2` call must be multiple of 4194304
bytes (except for last :meth:`files_upload_session_append_v2` with
``UploadSessionStartArg.close`` to ``True``, that may contain any
remaining data).
```

but I'm not sure how to implement this (since there is no `files_upload_async_session_append_v2()` for example). I can't find any examples in the Internet.

I tried the following code, but there is no upload speedup compare to sequential code

```py
async def upload_file(local_file_path: str, remote_folder_path: str, client: DropboxBase):
    """
        Uploads a file to Dropbox by chunks. This method uses v2 methods of Dropbox API.

        Example:
            upload_file('test.txt', '/Builds/', dropbox_client)

        :param local_file_path:
        :param remote_folder_path: A path to a folder on Dropbox, must end with a slash.
        :param client: Authorized Dropbox client.
        :return:
    """
    with open(local_file_path, 'rb') as file_stream:
        await __upload_file_by_chunks(file_stream, local_file_path, remote_folder_path, client)

async def test(data: bytes, cursor: UploadSessionCursor, client: DropboxBase, close: bool = False):
    client.files_upload_session_append_v2(data, cursor, close=close)


async def __upload_file_by_chunks(file_stream: BinaryIO, local_file_path: str, remote_folder_path: str, client: DropboxBase):
    # As default size for a chunk 4 MB were chosen. I think it's a good compromise between speed and reliability.
    # Also, Dropbox API guide (https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-performance-guide) says "Consider uploading chunks in multiples of 4 MBs."
    # ATTENTION: The maximum value can be placed here is 150 MB.
    chunk_size_bytes = 4 * 1024 * 1024

    session_id = __start_upload_session(client)
    cursor = __create_upload_session_cursor(file_stream, session_id)
    file_length = path.getsize(local_file_path)

    test_pool = set()

    # TODO: In theory this can be done in parallel, that should speed up the file upload.
    #  Maybe instead of while loop we can precalculate all chunks and then upload them in parallel.
    while file_stream.tell() < file_length:
        if __chunk_size_is_bigger_than_left_data(file_stream.tell(), file_length, chunk_size_bytes):
            chunk_size_bytes = file_length - file_stream.tell()
            test_pool.add(asyncio.create_task(test(file_stream.read(chunk_size_bytes), cursor, client, close=True)))
            continue

        test_pool.add(asyncio.create_task(test(file_stream.read(chunk_size_bytes), cursor, client)))
        cursor = __create_upload_session_cursor(file_stream, session_id)

    await asyncio.wait(test_pool)

    client.files_upload_session_finish(bytes(), cursor, commit=CommitInfo(
        path=__construct_remote_file_path(local_file_path, remote_folder_path)))


def __start_upload_session(client: DropboxBase) -> int:
    session_start_response = client.files_upload_session_start(bytes(), session_type=UploadSessionType.concurrent)
    return session_start_response.session_id

...

asyncio.run(upload_file(file_name, DROPBOX_TEST_FOLDER, client))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "concurrent" mode is a good way to optimize the upload of a file to Dropbox using upload sessions, as it allows you to upload multiple pieces of the file in parallel.

There's a code sample here that shows how to use the "concurrent" mode, including using `files_upload_session_append_v2`:

https://github.com/dropbox/Developer-Samples/tree/master/Blog/performant_upload

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. For some reason, the speed boost is not what I expected - with 32 threads/24MB chunk size I have an upload time of 1 minute 40 sec, while without parallelism for 4MB chunk size I have 2 minutes 10 sec :/

Comment: You may need to tweak the configuration to serve your particular use case well. Note that there are two different thread count limits you can configure in that example. If you're only uploading one file, you may want to increase [`concurrent_thread_count`](https://github.com/dropbox/Developer-Samples/blob/master/Blog/performant_upload/config.ini.example#L36) rather than `batch_thread_count`. And depending on your scenario, you may want to change the chunk size. Your network connection speed itself also will play a major factor regardless.

Comment: Right, the problem was only related to my network. On the production network, it works as expected. Thank you for your time